# React Router6: issue while passing element to private route

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router-dom

I am trying to create a PrivateRoute component as:

```js
import { useStoreState } from 'easy-peasy';
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Navigate, Route } from 'react-router-dom';

// import styles from'./index.module.scss';

interface PrivateRouteProps {
  path: string;
  element: Component;
}
const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({
  path,
  element,
  children,
  ...props
}) => {
  const isLoggedIn = useStoreState((state: any) => state.user.isLoggedIn);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  return (
    <Route path={path} element={element} {...props}>
      {children}
    </Route>
  );
};
export default PrivateRoute;
```

and this is how I am trying to use it:

```js
function App() {
  return (
    <div className={styles.app}>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          <PrivateRoute path="cohort" element={MyComponent}></PrivateRoute>
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

but while using the PrivateRoute I am getting this error:
[image]

Comment: is your types are updated ? have you tried `yarn upgrade @types/react@latest` ?

Comment: @SangeetAgarwal Sorry it was misplaced.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My previous attempt of `element: React.ComponentType<any>` solved the typescript error but then the new error was

> Error: [PrivateRoute] is not a  component. All component children of  must be a <Route> or <React.Fragment>

So, with v6 react router only Route components can be a child of Routes. see the v6 docs & you'll see the authentication pattern is to use a wrapper component to handle the auth check and redirect.

The old v5 pattern will not work any more.

This is how your `PrivateRoute` should look like. I've commented out the previous code so you can see the changes I've made.

```
import { useStoreState } from "easy-peasy";
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { Navigate, Route } from "react-router-dom";

// import styles from'./index.module.scss';

interface PrivateRouteProps {
  path: string;
  element: React.ComponentType<any>;
  // element: Component;
}
// const PrivateRoute: React.FC<PrivateRouteProps> = ({
//   path,
//   element,
//   children,
//   ...props
// }) => {
const PrivateRoute = ({ children }: { children: JSX.Element }) => {
  const isLoggedIn = useStoreState((state: any) => state.user.isLoggedIn);

  if (!isLoggedIn) {
    return <Navigate to="/login" />;
  }

  // return (
  //   <Route path={path} element={element} {...props}>
  //     {children}
  //   </Route>
  // );

  return children;
};

export default PrivateRoute;
```

And, your `App` component will then look like so

```
export function App() {
  return (
    <div>
      <Router>
        <Routes>
          <Route path="" element={<Home />}></Route>
          <Route path="login" element={<Login />}></Route>
          {/* <PrivateRoute path="cohort" element={MyComponent}></PrivateRoute> */}
          <Route
            path="cohort"
            element={
              <PrivateRoute>
                <MyComponent />
              </PrivateRoute>
            }
          />
        </Routes>
      </Router>
    </div>
  );
}
```

And, here the link to the codesandbox https://codesandbox.io/s/reactrouterv6wayofdoingthings-0nmkg?file=/src/App.tsx